# Why not all the values in one columns not converted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have inserted csv file to sql server and doing now casting. there is One column contains value like (166742.9659) as nvarchar and i wanted to convert it to decimal. 
my query was like this

```
CAST([amount] AS decimal(18,2))     AS [amount]
```

I got the following message:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

then i tried the query just to see which values aws not converted

```
TRY_CAST([amount] AS decimal(18,2))     AS [amount]
```

then i got number of NULL values. When i checked this values in the original csv file i found that those numbers have the same format of the value which have been converted successfully.
for example: 
this number **17011343.12** was successfully converted
this number **166742.9659 ** get null value

so is there anybody please can understand what happened ??

Comment: i tried LTRIM & RTRIM but got the same results

Comment: My first thought was the additional decimal places in the one that failed but that doesn't seem to cause a problem https://rextester.com/NITVJ39579. Maybe some non printing character  in the value?

Comment: Works for every version of SQL Server from 2012 on... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=ece04052ad5705dd7db14687a9d25828

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This suggests that you have unexpected characters in the string.  And that requires debugging.  So this is intended to help you with that.

You need some forensics on the query.  One place to start is:

```
select amount, len(amount), len(ltrim(rtrim(amount)))
from staging
where TRY_CAST([amount] AS decimal(18,2)) is null and
      amount is not null;
```

You will need to manually count the characters to see if the lengths match what you see.  If they do, then it suggests that one of the digits is really something else (say a `O` or `l` -- capital O or lower case l).  Or perhaps the decimal place is some other period.

If they do not match, then nefarious other characters have found their way into your file.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, that's was helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table
(
id int identity,
a nvarchar(100)
);

insert into @t(a) values (cast(0xfeff3100320033002E003400350036003700 as nvarchar(100)));

insert into @t(a)
select top 1000 replace(left(newid(), 13), '-', '.')
from master.dbo.spt_values;

select a, try_cast(a as decimal(18,5)) as trycast, 
    try_cast(
      cast(
        convert(varbinary(max), 
        '0x' + cast('' as xml).query('
        let $str := xs:string(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("bincol")))
        for $p in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25)[. <= string-length($str) div 4] (: max input length=25 :)
        let $s := substring($str, 4*($p - 1)+1, 4) [. = ("3000" , "3100", "3200", "3300", "3400", "3500", "3600", "3700", "3800", "3900", "2E00")] (: keep only digits and dot :)
        return <a>{$s}</a>').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1) 
      as nvarchar(max)) --string, containing digits and dot(s)
    as decimal(18,5) --...conversion will fail for multiple dots 
    ) as purgeddecimal
from 
(
    select id, a, cast(a as varbinary(max)) as bincol
    from @t
) as t
order by id;
```